# How to write a while() loop for an Iterable<Object> in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala and I want to transform a line of code from Java. I've tried 2 methods in scala, but they didn't work. The class `ResultScanner` comes from Apache HBase - [ResultScanner](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/ResultScanner.html) and the same for the [Result](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html) class

**Java**

```
for(Result r : resultScanner) System.out.println(r)
```

**Scala**

```
while(resultScanner.hasNext)      // error[1]
  println(resultScanner.next())

//error[1]: value hasNext is not a member of org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner
```

I've tried the following as well :

```
resultScanner.foreach(println(_)) // error[2]

// error[2]: value foreach is not a member of org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner
```

Comment: I found this `while(resultScanner.iterator().hasNext()) println(resultScanner.next())` But it was wrong, because it shows only the half of the results expected. The reason is the result had been incremented on while condition when I do `iterator()`, I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Include `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._` for Java to Scala collections portability. Then invoke `asScala` on the collection,

```
resultScanner.asScala foreach println
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ArrayList create ResultScanner and try:

```scala
scala> import java.util
import java.util

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> val jList = new util.ArrayList[Int]
jList: java.util.ArrayList[Int] = []

scala> jList.add(2)
res4: Boolean = true

scala> jList.add(6)
res5: Boolean = true

scala> val iterable = iterableAsScalaIterable(jList)
iterable: Iterable[Int] = Wrappers(2, 6)

scala> iterable.foreach(println)
2
6
```

**Note:**

Choose `JavaConverters._` instead of `JavaConverters._`

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> import java.util
import java.util

scala> val jList = new util.ArrayList[Int]
jList: java.util.ArrayList[Int] = []

scala> jList.add(2)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> jList.add(6)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> val iterable = jList.asScala
iterable: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = Buffer(2, 6)

scala> val iterable:Iterable[Int] = jList.asScala
iterable: Iterable[Int] = Buffer(2, 6)
```